# DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message. However I can log the thing I am trying to send to console, the data being sent is from MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, discord, discord.js

```
Code:
const ModSchema = require('../models/ModSchema');

module.exports = {
    name: 'warns',
    description: "lists a members warns.",
    execute(message, args, client, Discord){
        const UserIDsearch = message.mentions.members.first().id;
        ModSchema.findOne({ 'UserID': UserIDsearch }, function (err, Punishments) {
            if (err) return console.log(err);
            let data = Punishments;
            console.log(data);
            message.channel.send(data);
        })
    }
}
Error Message:
(node:7397) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message
    at RequestHandler.execute (/Users/mynamegoeshere/ESENTRIX CLONE FILE/Esentrix-Bot-5/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:154:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (/Users/mynamegoeshere/ESENTRIX CLONE FILE/Esentrix-Bot-5/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:39:14)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:7397) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:7397) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

What I want to send in Discord: 
"Punishments": [
    {
      "PunishType": "Mute",
      "Moderator": "Poetic",
      "Reason": "test",
      "Time": "10000 ms"
    }
```

This is the code used to query the data from a MongoDB Database, the data is stored as a JSON file but I think it is stringified if you set it to a const/let. Please let me know how I can send the data because I cannot seem to find the problem. Keep in mind that the text that I am trying to send can be logged to console with console.log(data);, but I get the above error when using message.channel.send(data); Please let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try something like

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'warns',
    description: "lists a members warns.",
    execute(message, args, client, Discord){
        const UserIDsearch = message.mentions.members.first().id;
        ModSchema.findOne({ 'UserID': UserIDsearch }, function (err, Punishments) {
            if (err) return console.log(err);
            if(Punishments){
                let data = Punishments;
                console.log(data);
                message.channel.send(data);
            }
        })
    }
}
```

or just to make sure its stringified, try

```
JSON.stringify(data)
```

Comment: Mark the answer as correct since it worked